# Implement multiple times the same generic interface that includes properties with different type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, properties, interface

Well from the beginning, I've got a simple generic interface:

```
public interface IItemContainer<T> where T : Item
{
    T ChosenItem { get; set; }
}
```

And an class that implements it multiple times:

```
public class ChosenItemsContainer : IItemContainer<FabulousItem>, IItemContainer<NiceItem>, IItemContainer<GreedyItem>
{

    public FabulousItem ChosenItem { get; set; }
    NiceItem IItemContainer<NiceItem>.ChosenItem { get; set; }
    GreedyItem IItemContainer<GreedyItem>.ChosenItem { get; set; }
}
```

I can't make the ChosenItems of types NiceItem and GreedyItem public, and also I can't access it like this:

```
ChosenItem<GreedyItem> = new GreedyItem();
```

cuz' I've got an error:

```
'GreedyItem' is a type, which is not valid in the current context
```

Is there anyway to use those props in this manner or I've got it all wrong and should do It with Dictionary or other way?

Comment: I would just implement the interface with the baseclass `public class ChosenItemsContainer : IItemContainer<Item>`  and cast it when needed. (with  `OfType<>()` etc. It's kinda strange a class implements the same interface twice and these classes shares the same baseclass.

Comment: `((IItemContainer<GreedyItem>)containerInstance).ChosenItem = new GreedyItem();` -- not very nice. Other way would be to have `public ChosenGreedyItem` property and `public ChosenNiceItem` property and so on and use those in the specific interface properties.

Comment: Consider adding a paragraph with your goals or what you are trying to achieve. The code seems designed to forcibly use generics, but that is not necessarily the only or best approach. What is a good approach depends on your goals which we do not know.

Comment: I have an Form (Winform app) which has an submodules that operates on various types of Items (Module1 uses GreedyItems, Module2 uses NiceItems etc.) and I am providing to users an UI to choose a set of each item types and also allow them to focus on one specific from the set. The sets can be changed in submodules, so I need the so called "base form" to communicate with submodules about items in the sets. That's what I'am using this and another one IItemCollectionContainer<Item> to actually get and set items in base form and submodules (which also implements those two interfaces but only once).

Comment: The @JeroenvanLangen approach is not an option since I need to store an instance of each implemented type independently.

Comment: @KamilStadryniak I wrote an answer, which will take care of the typecasts in usage code by using extra properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you like to keep your generic IItemContainer you can implement a GetChosenItem and SetChosenItem method like this.

```
public class ChosenItemsContainer : IItemContainer<FabulousItem>, IItemContainer<NiceItem>, IItemContainer<GreedyItem>
{
    FabulousItem IItemContainer<FabulousItem>.ChosenItem { get; set; }
    NiceItem IItemContainer<NiceItem>.ChosenItem { get; set; }
    GreedyItem IItemContainer<GreedyItem>.ChosenItem { get; set; }

    public T GetChosenItem<T>()
        where T : Item
    {
        return ((IItemContainer<T>)this).ChosenItem;
    }

    public void SetChosenItem<T>(T value)
        where T : Item
    {
        ((IItemContainer<T>)this).ChosenItem = value;
    }
}
```

Which comes very close to what you were trying to do.

```
container.SetChosenItem<NiceItem>(new NiceItem());
```

Comment: Well it seems to work as expected, and looks quite elegant too, I'll wait for the day to end and mark this as an answer if nothing "considerably more elegant" appears until then. :)

Comment: Very nice solution, but... When passing a valid Item derived class, which was not implemented, could result in a runtime error. You'd rather fix error on compile time.

Comment: You are doing an unnecessary cast here. This will require access to the interface map.

Answer (score 3):

Yours is a case explicit interface implementations were made for. You give your conflicting items a unique name and forward the items to the interface. That also avoids any naming confusions:

```
public class ChosenItemsContainer : IItemContainer<FabulousItem>, IItemContainer<NiceItem>, IItemContainer<GreedyItem> {

    public FabulousItem ChosenFabulousItem { get; set; }
    public NiceItem ChosenNiceItem { get; set; }
    public GreedyItem ChosenGreedyItem { get; set; }

    FabulousItem IItemContainer<FabulousItem>.ChosenItem {
        get {
            return ChosenFabulousItem;
        }
        set {
            ChosenFabulousItem = value;
        }
    }
    NiceItem IItemContainer<NiceItem>.ChosenItem {
        get {
            return ChosenNiceItem;
        }
        set {
            ChosenNiceItem = value;
        }
    }
    GreedyItem IItemContainer<GreedyItem>.ChosenItem {
        get {
            return ChosenGreedyItem;
        }
        set {
            ChosenGreedyItem = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Assignment is simple:

```
container.ChosenFabulousItem = new FabulousItem();
container.ChosenNiceItem = new NiceItem();
container.ChosenGreedyItem = new GreedyItem();
```

If you have more complex conversion logic in the background (e.g. you assign a `FaboulousItem` and need to convert it into a `NiceItem`), you can do so by providing getters and/or setters for your public properties.

Comment: I like this simple solution +1

Comment: Nice, but when I want to use my generic ChosenItem within GenericMethod<T>() where T : Item then if...else maddness begins.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely wrong. As you should know you cannot make same names for member items (properties, fields etc. ). It will confuse compiler.

I would suggest to modify your interface a bit like :

```
public interface IItemContainer
{
    List<Item> ChosenItems { get; set; }
    T ChosenItem<T>() where T : Item;
}
```

Now in your implementation :

```
public class ItemContainer : IItemContainer
{
    IItemContainer.ChosenItems
    {
        get { // your implementation
        }
        set { // your implementation
        }
    }

    T IItemContainer.ChosenItem<T>()
    {
        return ((IItemContainer)this).ChosenItems.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

This method will let you store different objects that derive from `Item` and return desired one using `ChosenItem<T>()` method.

**EDIT:**

> I've got another interface which operates on List of Items, cuz' some submodules works only on one Item, and some only on set. I need also to store an instance of each implemented type independently.

You can always use something like a *factory collection* ( dont know if the name is correct ).

```
public class ChosenItemCollection 
{
    Dictionary<Type, Item> _fac = new Dictionary<Type, Item>();

    public T Add<T>(T item) where T : Item
    {
        if(!_fac.ContainsKey(typeof(T))
        {
             _fac.Add(typeof(T), item);
        }
        else
        {
            _fac[typeof(T)] = item;
        }
    }

    public T GetChosenItem<T>() where T : Item
    {
        if(_fac.ContainsKey(typeof(T))
            return _fac[typeof(T)];

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in your interface instead of `List<Item> ChosenItems` you can do `ChosenItemCollection ChosenItems`.

Using this in your example :

```
GreedyItem item = // ... 
ItemContainer.ChosenItems.Add(item);
ItemContainer.ChosenItem.ChosenItem<GreedyItem>();
```

Comment: I've got another interface which operates on List of Items, cuz' some submodules works only on one Item, and some only on set. I need also to store an instance of each implemented type independently.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Pidon` has a nice solution. But could result in a runtime error when using not implemented `Item` derives.

Another solution could be adding properties which will do the casts to the implemented types:

```
public class ChosenItemsContainer : IItemContainer<FabulousItem>, IItemContainer<NiceItem>, IItemContainer<GreedyItem>
{

    // these properties are only visible when casting to the correct
    // interface. Which the public properties below will do.
    FabulousItem IItemContainer<FabulousItem>.ChosenItem { get; set; }
    GreedyItem IItemContainer<GreedyItem>.ChosenItem { get; set; }
    NiceItem IItemContainer<NiceItem>.ChosenItem { get; set; }



    // return this as IItemContainer<FabulousItem>
    public IItemContainer<FabulousItem> AsFabulous
    {
        get
        {
            return (IItemContainer<FabulousItem>)this;
        }
    }

    // return this as IItemContainer<NiceItem>
    public IItemContainer<NiceItem> AsNice
    {
        get
        {
            return (IItemContainer<NiceItem>)this;
        }
    }

    // return this as IItemContainer<GreedyItem>
    public IItemContainer<GreedyItem> AsGreedy
    {
        get
        {
            return (IItemContainer<GreedyItem>)this;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
ChosenItemsContainer container = new ChosenItemsContainer();

container.AsFabulous.ChosenItem = new FabulousItem();
container.AsNice.ChosenItem = new NiceItem();
container.AsGreedy.ChosenItem = new GreedyItem();
```

This way each implemented type has it's own ChosenItem instance. I think this is a clean solution without cluttering of generic `<T>` in code.